# How can I Order a List<string[]>?

Tags: c#, csv

Im working with this list:

```
 List<string[]> parserData = ReadParserData(@"C:/File.csv", ',');
```

And Inside of my file i have:

```
    2,Sam,500.00
    6,Mike,400.00
    8,Robert,156.00
    3,Steve,100.85
    9,Anderson,234.90
```

in the meaning order: ID, Name, Salary.

```
   private static List<string[]> ReadParserData(string path, char delimiter)
    {
        var parserData = new List<string[]>();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] row = line.Split(delimiter);
                parserData.Add(row);
            }
        }
        return parserData;
    }
```

How can i sort, by ascending to descending salary?.
I'm saving a CSV file like this way...

```
  using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:/AscendingSalary.csv"))
            {
                foreach (string[] row in parserData)
                {
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();

                    foreach (string s in row)
                    {
                        sb.Append(s + ",");
                    }

                    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
                    sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just parse salary (third item in row) and use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) or [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534855(v=vs.100).aspx) methods to order lines:

```
parsedData.OrderBy(row => Decimal.Parse(row[2]))
```

But I suggest you to create some `Person` class which will store your data in readable way

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Parsing

```
var people = from line in File.ReadLines(path)
             let parts = line.Split(delimiter)
             select new Person {
                Id = Int32.Parse(parts[0]),
                Name = parts[1],
                Salary = Decimal.Parse(parts[2])
             };
```

Then you will be able to sort list of people by salary this way

```
people.OrderBy(p => p.Salary)
```

Much more readable.

NOTE: There is handy [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

---

For saving person data you can simply write formatted lines:

```
var lines = from p in people
            orderby p.Salary
            select String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", p.Id, p.Name, p.Salary);

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:/AscendingSalary.csv", lines);
```

Comment: Many thanks Sergey it is very usefull your answer and very entendible too, but how can i do it without using the function split?